# How to use different Google account for selected services?

Tags: google-docs, google-account

I have account A of Google for work stuff and account B for registering other accounts (which hides my identity). I would like to log in to Google Drive, Gmail and Blogger with account A and other services like YouTube, Google Search, Google Calendar, Google Maps and services which log in with Google account like StackExchange with account B. Usually, I use account B mostly so I set it as a default account, but when I need to access my Google Docs, I need to sign out to switch to A because [Google doesn't allow to switch](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/181601?hl=en). I have tried using multiple profiles, but it doesn't help. Is it possible to use different Google account for selected services? How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Using different browsers  (eg Chrome for Account A, Firefox for Account B) is the best approach iMHO.

Google has tried to provide multi-account support in some products, but success is inconsistent, and sometimes what works today doesn't work again tomorrow.

Comment: This has been my approach for years. I use Chrome for my personal stuff and Firefox when I need to get work stuff and keep it all very separate.

Comment: Using different browsers is not convenient. Account A is only for work but account B is also for work and other stuff. For example, sometime you need to open a link in email (account A) and use account B to log in to use.